# Repeated convolution of a pdf of the product of two (independent?) random variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, convolution

Let $p\in \mathbb R$ and $k,n\in \mathbb N$ be fixed constants with $ k << n$.

Let $\bf A$ be a random vector of positive real numbers summing to $p$, generated as follows: choose $n$ real numbers independently and uniformly between $0$ and $1$ to be the coordinates of $\bf A$, then normalize so their sum is $p$.

Let $\bf x$ be a random "mask" vector of length $n$, generated as follows. We choose a random subset of $k$ entries of $\bf x$ to be nonzero. Each of the nonzero entries is chosen uniformly in the range $(1,100)$, independently of each other (and of $\bf A$).

> Question: How can we determine the cumulative distribution function of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} {\bf A}_i{\bf x}_i$?

Edit: I did a bit of research and found out how to do steps 2 and 3 in the roadmap below ( I plan to do step 3 using Chernoff Bounds to approximate ). Thus, all that is left to do is find the PDF of $A_1$, but this is really difficult, because I can’t find the point of intersection in order to integrate. Also, even I found the limits of integration, I’m not quite sure how I would take the derivative of such a complex function. I am currently trying to find a solution, but I welcome any input!

Comment: This is a well-asked question, but I think you should not hope for an exact answer. The coordinates of $\bf A$ are very messily dependent on each other, so any convolution is out of the question. Finding the joint distribution for $\bf A$ is hard enough.

Comment: Is the CDF of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} {\bf A}_i{\bf x}_i$ your final goal, or are you finding it on your way to something else? Maybe there are easier ways to get there.

Comment: This would be my final goal. Mike, there is something that could help me out with respect to that dependency. $k$ is a lot less than $n$, so any changes in $k$ could be compensated for by the values in $A$ that are multiplied by $x$ in the dot product. For example, if one value in $A$ changes by 0.1, the other values in $A$ could counter it, because only $k$ values matter. In short, we might be able consider the values of $A$ as independent random variables. In that case, can the problem be simplified?

Comment: multiplied by $0$ in the dot product I mean.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer yet, but I want to get some thoughts out there.

- You can just solve the problem for $p=1$. Since $p$ is just a scale factor, it is simple to determine the distribution for general $p$ from the $p=1$ case.
- We can simplify things by not choosing the $k$ nonzero entries of $\bf x$ randomly, but instead always having them be the first $k$ coordinates (because the $A_i$ are identically distributed, so it does not matter which $k$ are used). Therefore, instead of an $n$-fold sum, we just need to work with the $k$-fold sum
  $$
  \sum_{i=1}^k A_i U_i,\qquad U_i\sim \text{Unif}(1,100)
  $$
  Above, the $x_i$ have been replaced with the simpler $U_i$ that are always nonzero.
- Your idea of assuming that the collection $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_k\}$ is independent for calculation purposes is probably a good approximation, as long as $k\ll n$. Therefore, you just need to do three things:

  1. Determine the pdf of a single coordinate, $A_1$.
  2. Determine the pdf of $A_1U_1$, by convolving the previous pdf with the uniform pdf. Call this pdf $f_{A_1U_1}(x)$.
  3. Compute the $k$-fold convolution of $f_{A_1U_1}(x)$ with itself.

However, even with all of these simplifications, step 1 of determining the pdf of $A_1$ is still quite hard. In what follows, I will let $V_1,\dots,V_n$ be the *unnormalized* values of $A_i$, so that each $V_i\sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$, independently of each other.

- Let $W=V_2+V_3+\dots+V_k$. First, compute the pdf of $W$. There are two ways to do this:

  - Compute the pdf exactly, using the the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution). The resulting pdf is a piecewise function which is a certain polynomial on each piece.
  - If $k$ is large enough, you can just use the central limit theorem and approximate $W$ by a normal normal random variable whose mean is $(k-1)/2$ and whose variance is $(k-1)/12$.
- Since $V_1$ and $W$ are independent, and we have the pdf of each, we easily get the joint pdf $f(v,w)$ of $(V_1,W)$. Since$$A_1=\frac{V_1}{V_1+W}, $$ you can first find the $P(A_1\le a)$ of $A_1$ by integrating $f(v,w)$ over the region defined by
  $$
  0\le v\le 1,\;\; 0\le w\le (k-1),\;\; \frac{v}{v+w}\le a
  $$
  This function of $a$ must then be differentiated to get the pdf of $A$. This is the part that I am too scared to attempt, but perhaps with this road map you or someone else can figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for this! I do have a question though - why isn't the PDF of $A$ a uniform distribution, as it is a scaled version of ${V_1, V_2, ... , V_n}$? This might be a bad question though, as I have no background in statistics. However, I ran a simulation on this for high values of $n$ and $p$, and it seemed to resemble a uniform distribution.

Comment: @bad-at-math Scaling by a constant is OK, but scaling by a random quantity can skew the distribution, so $A_1$ is not exactly uniform. [Here is the distribution of $A_1$ for n = 100 and p = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CN3t.png). Note it is mostly uniform, but there is a bit of curved dropoff to the right. Note also that it is not uniform on the range $(0,p/n)$. It is something more like $(0,1.8p/n)$.

Comment: Interesting...why is it that the distribution of $A$ is different from the distribution from $A_1$? Is there something erroneous with how I generated $A$?

Comment: Also, why is $0 \leq w\leq 1$ a constraint?

Comment: First of all, as I see it, $A$ is a random vector, while $A_1$ is just a random number, so they are entirely different animals. How are you getting a single histogram for the random before $A$? If you include you code, maybe I could see the error. Re your second comment, that was my mistake, now fixed.

Comment: I was thinking that since each $A_1, A_2, $ etc. have the same distribution, the vector $A$ would have that distribution. I have edited the problem above to show the code for generating the histogram.

Comment: @bad-at-math I can see now your code is computing the incorrect thing. Simulating the probability distribution means you have to call `gen_A(n,p)` many times, and extract the coordinate `A[0]` from each of the instances, then make a histogram of the expected value. You are just calling `gen_A(n,p)` once and making a histogram of all of that data. While it is true that each coordinate of `gen_A(n,p)` is distributed like $A_1$, the coordinate are dependent, so they do not count as independent copies of $A_1$.

Comment: I see, I had forgotten the dependence of the values on each other. Thank you! I'm working on steps 1 and 2, so I'll post those in a bit.

Comment: Man, finding those limits of integration is tough! Any ideas? I know how to find step 2, but step 1 is giving me a lot of trouble.

Comment: @bad-at-math Sorry friend, everything I was able to figure out was in my answer. I agree it is tough.